# Find value in Excel from Outlook

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am having trouble performing an Excel vlookup from Outlook.

Here is what I am trying to accomplish:
- loop through each email in inbox
- if the subject line meets a criteria then get value
- go into excel and vlookup that value
- if the value exists, activate the cell and shift over to get the text value of the adjacent cell and bring it back to outlook to insert in an email (not there yet).

This is the code I'm stuck on (keep getting the 'object required' error):

```
Dim objExcel As Object

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
.

Dim result As String

result = Right(subject, 7)

Dim found As Boolean 'can this be boolean?I just want to know if its exists or not

found = objExcel.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(result, Sheet1.Range("A:A"), 1, False)
```

I thought the objExcel would replace the 'Application' as that would default to Outlook.

I do want to mention, I have code that will open the excel file and loop through each email to get the subject line value successfully but I just cant seem to get control of it to perform functions.

**Update** - I tried this and it worked BUT the value was set to false when It should be true. Can you confirm this is correct?

```
Dim wrksht As Object 
Set wrksht = objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") 
Dim res As Boolean 

sourceWB.Activate 
With objExcel 
    res = Not IsError(objExcel.Match(result, wrksht.Range("A:A"), 0)) 
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Match if you just want to check if something exists.

**Note**: if you drop the `WorksheetFunction` then you can test the return value to see if it's an error: if you include `WorksheetFunction` then your code will generate a run-time error in the event there's no match.

```
 Dim objExcel As Object, wb As Object, sht As Object
 Dim result As String, found As Boolean

 Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
 '
 '
 Set wb = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("path_goes_here.xlsx")
 Set sht = wb.Sheets(1) 'or use the sheet tab name
 '


 result = Right(subject, 7)
 found = Not IsError(objExcel.Match(result, sht.Range("A:A"), 0))
```

**EDIT**: if you want a corresponding value from another column then you could do this -

```
 Dim m, answer
 result = Right(subject, 7)

 m = objExcel.Match(result, sht.Range("A:A"), 0)

 If Not IsError(m) Then
     answer = sht.Cells(m, "B").Value
 Else
     answer = "Not found!"
 End If
```

Comment: Hi @TimWilliams, thanks for your response. Although I like your suggestions, I am still getting this 'object required' error. The code is in outlook so do I have to activate the excel workbook to get that control and perform the action?

Comment: the only 2 other pieces of code i have related to the excel object are the following:
With objExcel
            .Visible = True
            .EnableEvents = False
            End With

strFile = path to file

Set sourceWB = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(strFile)
            sourceWB.Activate

I should be creating an object for worksheets?

Comment: I tried this and it worked BUT the value was set to false when It should be true. can you confirm this is correct? @TimWilliams

Dim wrksht As Object
        
        
        Set wrksht = objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
            
          Dim res As Boolean
            sourceWB.Activate
            With objExcel
            res = Not IsError(objExcel.Match(result, wrksht.Range("A:A"), 0))
            End With

Comment: What type of value is `result` ?

Comment: String value @TimWilliams

Comment: It's OK to add new code to your question as an update (I did it for you this time...)  Code in comments isn't too readable.  If you use MATCH() on the worksheet does it find the value you want?

Comment: it returns 2 but it actually only appears once in my file - I dont understand where 2 is coming from. The vlookup i tried, returns true (displaying the value) . I also tried changing the res variable as an integer but had no luck...

Comment: MATCH() returns the *position* of `result` in ColA.  See my edit above.

Comment: OK. it still doesn't work in the VBA though. anything else i can try? @TimWilliams

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use the following:

```
For Each cell In objExcel.Range("A:A")

    If CStr(cell) = result Then
           .
           .
           .
```

thanks  @TimWilliams for working with me on this!!

Answer (score 0):

here is a full example

```
Sub vLookup()

    Dim objExcel As Object
    Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

    objExcel.Visible = True

    Dim xlWB As Object
    Set xlWB = objExcel.Workbooks.Add

    Dim xlSheet As Object
    Set xlSheet = xlWB.Sheets("Sheet1")

    Dim formula As String
    Dim result As String

    xlSheet.Range("a3") = "abc123"
    xlSheet.Range("a4") = "abc"
    xlSheet.Range("a5") = "123"

Stop   ' press F8 to single-step from here

    result = "abc123"                                        ' this will be found
    formula = "IFNA(MATCH(""" & result & """,A:A,0),0)"      ' cell formula: =IFNA(MATCH("abc123",A:A,0),0)   return 0 if not found
    Debug.Print objExcel.Evaluate(formula)                   ' returns 3 in this example

   ' press ctrl-G to see output of Debug.Print

    result = "aaa"                                           ' this will not be found
    formula = "IFNA(MATCH(""" & result & """,A:A,0),0)"      ' cell formula: =IFNA(MATCH("aaa",A:A,0),0)   return 0 if not found
    Debug.Print objExcel.Evaluate(formula)                   ' returns 0 in this example

    Set xlSheet = Nothing
    Set xlWB = Nothing
    Set objExcel = Nothing

End Sub
```